# Updating Open Graph item

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a web site that users can build their TV watch list. They can save how many episodes in a show have they watched.

As some shows may have over 200 episodes, pushing one event per one episode is not really feasible so I use only one event for a show.

How do I update the episodes count after the user have updated their data?

(User cannot watch the same show multiple times, so one show can only have one open graph event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I got it, you have two possibilities:

1. If you want to update the open graph item real-time, you have to call one event per episode.
2. If you are fine with updating later, you can use cookies or session variables to save the count of episodes per show and you can push the count to the open graph event in interval time. But you have to make sure if the user closes the browser suddenly, your counter does not get lost (you can use the `window.onunload` or similar jquery alternatives).

Comment: I can't call one per episode, as that would be over 200 events on some show. For the second one, the user may come back to the site at any time and update the episode count. The user might come back after the delayed push interval.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how does it make a problem if an user comes back later?

Comment: If the user come back later after the event have been pushed I need to republish the event (as editing the published event is not possible). As episode|sum is displayed in aggregation, this results in doubling the episode count of that TV series.

Comment: Do not republish, get it first (if you don't know the count), remove it and then publish it.

Comment: Guess I have to go with that way. Thanks for the help!